# How to remove the duplicate words in Emacs?

Tags: elisp, words

One can find [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DuplicateLines) various ways to remove all duplicate lines in Emacs by preserving the first occurrence. Also [Emacs 24.4 introduces the command `delete-duplicate-lines`](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/03/01/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-delete-duplicate-lines/).

I am wondering if there is a similar way to to delete all duplicate words by preserving the first occurrence of each words.

Comment: If you can format your document one word per line, you'd solve the problem. Can you share more details on how the original document is formatted?

Comment: @wvxvw The original text is a very big text file (no particular structure). If there is a simple function which formats the document one word per line I would be glad to learn about it.

Comment: @Name You can use `query-replace` to replace spaces with newlines and then `delete-duplicate-lines`. I am assuming that this document is just a list of words. Because if the document has proper meaningful sentences, they will get butchered.

Comment: @kaushalmodi thank you for this simple idea.

Comment: If there is a direct solution without introducing new lines I would be interested.

Comment: @Name You can then select the whole buffer and auto fill to collapse the new lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command (minimally-tested) will collect all of the words in the buffer and display the unique ones (ignoring case) in a new buffer.

```el
(defun show-unique-words (&optional alphabetical)
  "Collect all of the unique words in the current buffer and
display them in a new buffer.  With prefix, alphabetize the
list."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((buf (buffer-name))
        (new (get-buffer-create "*Unique Words*"))
        (txt (delete-dups (mapcar #'downcase
                                  (split-string (buffer-string)
                                                nil nil
                                                "[^[:alnum:]]+")))))
    (with-current-buffer new
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (insert (format "%d unique words in the <%s> buffer:\n\n"
                      (length txt) buf))
      (cl-dolist (word (if alphabetical (sort txt #'string<) txt))
        (insert (concat word "\n"))))
    (pop-to-buffer new)))
```

Comment: Thanks I confirm that your works. I should mention that it is a little bit slow. The above comment of @kaushalmodi (a solution suggesting to replace the space with newlines then using delete-duplicate-lines) seems to be faster. But your function can be use to do other thing (e.g. sorting alphabetically).

Comment: By the way let me ask a question. When using your function interactively (with `M-x`) how to pass the argument `alphabetical` to `show-unique-words`. Using `M-x show-unique-words` doesn't sort alphabetically.  I  cannot figure out how to pass this argument to this command.

Comment: @Name: you can pass the prefix argument to the command with `C-u M-x show-unique-words`.  Have a look at the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) and [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixArgument) on the prefix argument for more information.

Comment: "a little bit slow" - `delete-dups` is `O(n²)`, using a hash-table to find duplicates (like `delete-duplicate-lines` does) would probably be faster for large inputs.